# javascript regex question

Tags: javascript, regex

i want to check for certain regex expression to make sure some string is followed by '::' and some number. The number can be between 1 and 999999999999.

for example: 'ACME LOCK & KEY::42443' should pass where 'ABC Inc.' should fail.

any help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
/::[1-9]\d{0,11}$/.test(str)
```

This will return true for every string that ends with `::` followed by an integer between 1 and 999999999999 inclusive.

Comment: will try.  will this work too? $(this).val().match(/(.*[::][0123456789])/g).   UPDATE: Gumbo, that works. thanks

Comment: it's returning the string and the number of digits.

Comment: Just a note, that this doesn't currently ensure a string exists prior to the `::`, so `::123` will pass.

Answer (score 2):

Here, this will match a string that ends in `::` followed by 1-12 digits.

```
/^.+::[1-9]\d{0,11}$/.test(stringToTest)
```

This also checks to make sure there is a string of at least 1 character prior to the `::`

Tests:

```
FAIL: asdf
PASS: asdf::123
FAIL: asdf::
FAIL: asdf::0
PASS: asdf::999999999999
FAIL: asdf::9999999999999
FAIL: ::asdf
FAIL: ::999
```